# How to parse HTTP response using Ruby

Tags: ruby, http

I've written a short snippet which sends a GET request, performs auth and checks if there is a 200 OK response (when auth success). Now, one thing I saw with this specific GET request, is that the response is always 200 irrespective of whether auth success or not.

The diff is in the HTTP response. That is when auth fails, the first response is 200 OK, just the same as when auth success, and after this then there is a second step. The page gets redirected again to the login page.

I am just trying to make a quick script which can check my login user and pass on my web application and tell me which auth passed and which didn't.

How should I check this? The sample code is like this:

```
def funcA(u, p)
  print_A("#{ip} - '#{u}' : '#{p}' - Pass")
end         

def try_login(u, p)
  path = '/index.php?uuser=#{u}&ppass=#{p}'
  r = send_request_raw({
    'URI' => 'path',
    'method' => 'GET'
  })

  if (r and r.code.to_i == 200)
    check = true
  end
  if check == true
    funcA(u, p)
  else
    out = "#{ip} - '#{u} - Fail"
    print_B(out)
  end
  return check, r
end
end
```

**Update**:
I also tried adding a new check for matching a 'Success/Fail' keyword coming in HTTP response. It didn't work either. But I now noticed that the response coming back seems to be in a different form. The Content-Type in response is text/html;charset=utf-8 though. And I am not doing any parsing so it is failing.

Success Response is in form of:

```
{"param1":1,"param2"="Auth Success","menu":0,"userdesc":"My User","user":"uuser","pass":"ppass","check":"success"}
```

Fail response is in form of:

```
{"param1":-1,"param2"="Auth Fail","check":"fail"}
```

So now I need some pointers on how to parse this response.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about http basic auth? Maybe you should show some code.

Comment: Added my code snippet..

Comment: Please note that [`and`/`or` is *not* the same as `&&`/`||` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/). Only the latter should be used when boolean logic is the intent.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with with ["net/http"](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI(url)
connection = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) 
@response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(url))
@httpStatusCode = @response.code
connection.finish
```

Comment: Hi Zach, the issue is, as I mentioned above, both valid & invalid login attempt give the same 200 response. After which, in case of failed auth, the page redirects to login screen..

Answer (score 0):

If there's a redirect from a 200 then it must be a javascript or meta redirect. So just look for that in the response body.

Comment: So how do you explain the redirect?

Comment: Okay I am not sure where is the redirect script. But how will that happen / help here? I am sending one GET request to do auth and receive auth pass/fail response...

Comment: It sounds like the response isn't redirecting, it's returning json and the calling page is redirecting based on the json values.